# FusedLocationClient's requestLocationUpdates Callbacks available

Tags: android, android-location, android-broadcastreceiver, android-gps

I am using android location sample code "**LocationUpdatesPendingIntent**" [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent) for requesting location updates even when the application is killed. It works very well in android 6, I don't turn on GPS in the device even then it starts showing me location but poor accuracy(that is acceptable). But in lollipop 5.1 it doesn't start and doesn't show any notification. Because it is getting null LAT and LONG. But it workes well even in lollipop 5.1 if I turn on GPS.

My Q is how to add some callback in:

```
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, getPendingIntent());
```

to check if it is able to get location LAT LONG or not. In lollipop case, it doesn't even fire broadcast.

Comment: Provide more code snippet like, what is `getPendingIntent()`? How do you define broadcast receiver if you are using broadcast for pending intent etc..

Comment: @Wizard please see link for code.